# How do I ConfigureServices() in a test assembly?

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-5

We're moving a WebAPI project from .NET 4.5.2. to .NET 5.0.

We're using NewtonSoft/Json.Net, and in the Startup.cs file of the WebAPI assembly, we have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    //...
}
```

I need to add some configuration to that, set some global custom converters, etc., and that's straightforward enough.

But I need to add configuration to my unit test assemblies, as well, set the same global custom converters.

So, my question - How do I configure services like this in a test assembly?

Comment: You generally don't. You would/should/could mock the calls to your configuration to have them return whatever you needed vs actually using them. If there is more to it than that, them I'm missing the nuances in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`JsonConvert` has a `DefaultSettings` delegate on it, which you can use to return a default `JsonSerializerSettings` instance:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new CustomConverter1(), new CustomConverter2() },
    // other settings ...
};
```

You should be able to set that up in your test assembly somewhere.  Then when you call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` in your tests it should use those settings by default.

Alternatively, you can just create a static `JsonSerializerSettings` instance somewhere and then pass it directly to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`.  Both methods have overloads that accept `JsonSerializerSettings`.